# How to convert a GridView to DataTable and sort the DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, datatable

I want to convert my GridView to a DataTable. Note: The GridView doesn't have a DataSource!
I want to sort the DataTable and put it back to the GridView, is it possible? Important is that my GridView must be sorted.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you populate the GridView in the first place? The DataTable might be easier to generate from the data source than from the GridView.

Comment: What about databinding the table to the gridview?

Comment: well i was going to suggest you to build your `DataSource` as answer to your last question ! !

Comment: I don't use a DataSource, I populate the GridView by importing items from Exchange Server, but this can be done with data from files. Very normal.

Comment: Converting your gridview to a datatable to do something and then back doesn't make any sense. I don't think you understand the fundamentals of server controls. They are just a collection of methods that emit certain html. They all should be able to be extended to do whatever you want.

Comment: well what i meant was building a `List` or maybe `DataTable` of data to be displayed by importing items from Exchange server. instead of looping the grid push the same into a `DataTable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `DataTable` in a `ViewState` when you bind for the first time.

```
gridView1.DataBind();
ViewState["dtbl"] = YourDataTable
```

and then do like...

```
protected void ComponentGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = ViewState["dtbl"] as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

        ComponentGridView.DataSource = dataView;
        ComponentGridView.DataBind();
    }
}

private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
            break;

        case SortDirection.Descending:
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
            break;
    }

    return newSortDirection;
}
```

Also take a look at this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Comment: Muhammad thank you, I was looking for it for days. Asked the same question in various forms. This works!

Comment: IT's great ! but will it make the website slow as I have a lot of data in the gridview ?

Comment: yah, how much is the more data in viewstate, it will impact the performance