# Sorting a gridview that has paging enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a list binding on a gridview.

```
HistoryGrid.DataSource = objGrid;
HistoryGrid.DataBind();

AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="True"  

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="hits" DataField="numberOfHits" 
  SortExpression="numberOfHits" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

This doesn`t work. What else do I need?

Comment: What kind of datasource are you binding to? You only get automatic sorting if you use one of a limited number of datasources.

Comment: I convert List to Datatable and now i have problem when change the page, then don`t show sorting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `list object as DataSource` then your sorting function will not work.

You can use a `DataTable as DataSource` to your Gridview and then it will work.

You can get more ideas from this thread: [How to convert a GridView to DataTable and sort the DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947780/how-to-convert-a-gridview-to-datatable-and-sort-the-datatable/5947912#5947912)

Comment: Thanks, I succeed, but in PageIndexChanging for pageing griedview, i have HistoryGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; and DataBind(). When i go to other page then it is not sorting data. My griedview is in update panel.

Comment: OK, I do with another dataView. Thanks again.