# How to sort a GridView with a ColumnHeader click when AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Tags: asp.net, gridview, columnheader, gridview-sorting

I have a gridview with AutoGenerateColumns="true" (in general I don't know what the columns will be). Is there any easy way to sort the grid by clicking on a column header? The only solutions I have found so far are for when AutoGenerateColumns="false"

Alternatively if I know one of the columns is going to be called `StatusId` is there a way to sort on this column only?

**Edit:**
I am manually updating the gridview's HeaderRow to make them more user friendly, this seems to be knocking things out.  Is there a way to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to Set `AllowSorting="true"` in the gridview ?

If that's not working for you then you can implement `custom Sorting`,

You can get custom sorting code from this thread: [How to convert a GridView to DataTable and sort the DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947780/how-to-convert-a-gridview-to-datatable-and-sort-the-datatable/5947912#5947912)

Comment: Yes I did, on further investigation I can see that I am updating the values in the gridview's HeaderRow to make them more user friendly.  This seems to be disabling the sorting links in the header.  I'll update the original post.